# Try to sign in through internet with Windows10 in Azure Active Directory, and we are out of the intranet with hybrid azure ad joined

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, hybrid

We are trying to sign in our Windows10 through internet, using their Azure AD users. We have used Azure AD joined and it works fine, but devices are not enrolled in the classic AD at the same time, so we lose GPOs.

Is there a way to sign in when you are not in the intranet and your device is hybrid Azure AD joined?

As far as we have tried it ever say "We can't sign you in with this credential because your domain isn't available. Make sure your device is connected to your organization's network..."

Maybe we are not using hybrid Azure AD joined properly and it is only posible by Azure AD joined?

We have our tenant ADFS federated if it could make any diference.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We think we get it. As far as we were working with an idp only with saml it didn't get the policy correctly. But, now that we are getting back to adfs, validation works perfect. Could it be the cause?

Comment: Nop, it was only a mistake. We receive the same message again that there is no domain at reach

Comment: Hybrid Azure AD joind only works when you are in your corporate network?